# ListBox async filtering, cancelling previous task on filter update

Tags: c#, asynchronous, wpf, async-await

I'm trying to come up with a nice way of filtering a `ListBox` asynchronously, to keep the UI responsive. The filtering gets fired off asynchronously each time the filter text is changed. This needs to cancel all previous filtering operations, so the updates to the filtered list don't conflict.

It seems that a list of `CancellationTokenSource` objects are required, so that each task can be cancelled independently.

Below is the best that I've managed to come up with so far. It seems to me that there must be a nicer way of doing it.

### ViewModel - MainPresenter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncListBoxFilter.ViewModels
{
    public sealed class MainPresenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private const int ITEM_COUNT = 1000;
        private static readonly Random Rand = new Random();

        private readonly ICollection<CancellationTokenSource> _cancellationTokenSources
            = new List<CancellationTokenSource>();

        private readonly ICollection<string> _allItems;
        private string _filterString;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public MainPresenter()
        {
            _allItems = new List<string>(
                Enumerable.Range(0, ITEM_COUNT)
                    .Select(_ => CreateRandomString()));
            FilteredItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(_allItems);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> FilteredItems { get; private set; }

        public string FilterString
        {
            get => _filterString;
            set
            {
                _filterString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                foreach (var source in _cancellationTokenSources)
                    source.Cancel();
                Task.Run(FilterAsync);
            }
        }

        private async Task FilterAsync()
        {
            var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _cancellationTokenSources.Add(source);
            var cancellationToken = source.Token;

            var filterString = FilterString; // Take a copy in case it changes
            var filtered = new ObservableCollection<string>();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var token = cancellationToken;

                foreach (var item in _allItems)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;

                    Thread.Sleep(1); // Slow down for testing

                    if (item.Contains(filterString ?? string.Empty))
                        filtered.Add(item);
                }
            }, cancellationToken);

            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"'{filterString}' Cancelled");
            }
            else
            {
                FilteredItems = filtered;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredItems));
                Console.WriteLine($"'{filterString}' Success");
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private static string CreateRandomString()
        {
            char CreateRandomChar() => (char) (65 + Rand.Next(26));
            return new string(Enumerable.Range(0, Rand.Next(3, 10))
                .Select(_ => CreateRandomChar()).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

### View - MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="AsyncListBoxFilter.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:AsyncListBoxFilter.ViewModels"
        Title="Async ListBox Filter"
        Height="600" Width="800"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainPresenter />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DockPanel>
        <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                 Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Margin="5" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems}" Margin="5" />
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution does not convince me because...

---

> ```
> public string FilterString
> {
>     get => _filterString;
>     set
>     {
>         _filterString = value;
>         OnPropertyChanged();
>         foreach (var source in _cancellationTokenSources)
>             source.Cancel();
>         Task.Run(FilterAsync);
>     }
> }
> ```

Don't do so much work in a setter. This is not the right place for that. You should implement it as a command like `FilterCommand` and fire it when the text changes.

---

The `CancellationTokenSource` must be disposed. You are not doing that yet.

---

You don't use `Thread.Sleep` when working with the `async/await` pattern because you don't want to put the entire thread to sleep. What you want is `Task.Delay`.

---

> ```
> var token = cancellationToken;
> ```

What purpose does this line have?

---

> ```
> FilteredItems = filtered;
> OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredItems));
> ```

The `FilterAsync` should not be triggering the property-changed event. The assignment should be all it does. On the other hand if its type is an `ObservableCollection` then you should use this for updates or make it an ordinary list becuase it's confusing when you have an observable that you are not using as such.

---

> ```
> ICollection<CancellationTokenSource> _cancellationTokenSources
> ```

You never remove any items from this collection and you also never dispose them.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I don't think I spent enough time putting together my question, as some side issues have distracted from my core interest of the best pattern for handling tasks overriding each other in this context. I'll have a think and update the question to be clearer.

Comment: @Scroog1 ok, but remember to not modify the code anymore... it's not allowed after receiving answers. If you intend to do it... it's better to ask a new question.

Comment: A fresh question might be a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider that _filterString and value might be the same, in which case do you want the rest of the setter logic to run?  There may be a lot work for very little benefit.

```
if(_filterString.Equals(value)) return;
OnPropertyChanged();
...
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you would use `_filterString.Equals(value)` and not `_filterString == value` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

One more point I want to add is that, Call filter after some duration when the user is entering the input and not for every text change. Setter should be simple and move the logic out of setter.

Comment: What's the benefit of the delay? And what is a sensible delay time in this context?

Comment: filtering and cancellation need not to be done, if the user is going to type still.  A sensible delay would be around 200 to 400 ms.